# Getting error while execute php bin/magento indexer:reindex please guide

Tags: magento2

Geeing error while execute index command

```
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
```

{"error":"no handler found for uri [/magento2_product_1_v2/document/_mapping?
include_type_name=true] and method [PUT]"}

please guide thank you!.

Comment: Now it's Fixed.

Because of the elasticsearch version 8.x I was face this issue now it's fixed after changing the version of 7.16.1. below url help me alote.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58656747/elasticsearch-job-for-elasticsearch-service-failed

Answer (score 0):

Run this command for check elastic search version

**Check your Elasticsearch Server Hostname and Elasticsearch Server Port before run command**

```
curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200'
```

You must have magento supported elastic version

Answer (score 0):

To use Elasticsearch with Magento 2.4.6-x I followed this post: [Magento 2.4.6 Install with Elasticsearch](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/365651/magento-2-4-6-install-with-elasticsearch/365655#365655)

Additionally I needed to update my Elasticsearch configuration and set

```yaml
indices.id_field_data.enabled: true
```

If you run ES in a docker container (with docker-compose) you can set this via env vars. Here is mine for reference:

```yaml
  elasticsearch:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:8.5.3
    container_name: elasticsearch
    restart: always
    environment:
      # Needed for Magento 2.4.6 to find products and show them in the shop.
      - indices.id_field_data.enabled=true
```

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue with Magento:2.4.6-p3, PHP:8.1, OpenSearch:2.5

**My solution:**

```
cd <magento_dir>
composer2.6.6 -vvv opensearch-project/opensearch-php --update-with-all-dependencies
composer2.6.6 update

php bin/magento setup:upgrade && \
php bin/magento setup:di:compile && \
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f -s standard && \
php bin/magento cache:flush && \
php bin/magento indexer:reindex

chown -R :www-data . && \
rm -rf var/cache/* && \
rm -rf var/page_cache/* && \
rm -rf generated/code/* && \
rm -rf var/log/* && \
find var generated vendor pub/static pub/media app/etc -type f -exec chmod g+w {} + && \
find var generated vendor pub/static pub/media app/etc -type d -exec chmod g+ws {} +
```

**NB:** create a backup of your working composer.* files

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a similar issue while running Opensearch 2.5-1.

Switching to Opensearch 1.2-0 resolved the problem.

https://community.magento.com/t5/Installing-Magento-2-x/OpenSearch-Version/m-p/515464/highlight/true#M11406