# Magento 2.4.6 Install with Elasticsearch

Tags: magento2, installation, elasticsearch, opensearch

I am trying to install Magento 2.4.6 with elastic search, I am using the following

```
--search-engine elasticsearch8 \ --elasticsearch-port 9232 \ --elasticsearch-index-prefix "test" \
```

but I just keep getting the error

```
Could not validate a connection to the OpenSearch. No alive nodes found in your cluster
```

Can anyone see what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's a bug in Magento 2.4.6. Could you try the following solutions?

**1...**
Try installing the official magento 2 Elasticsearch 8 Module:

```
composer require magento/module-elasticsearch-8 --with-all-dependencies
```

Then, try installing with following parameters:

```
bin/magento setup:install --disable-modules=Magento_InventoryElasticsearch,Magento_Elasticsearch8,Magento_Elasticsearch,Magento_OpenSearch
```

After setup is done, enable modules again (Dont enable Magento_OpenSearch again):

```
bin/magento module:enable Magento_InventoryElasticsearch Magento_Elasticsearch8 Magento_Elasticsearch
```

Change default search engine to elasticsearch 8:

```
bin/magento config:set catalog/search/engine 'elasticsearch8'
```

Start Magento Setup: (ElasticSearch 8 Service should run while starting setup again ;) )

```
bin/magento setup:upgrade bin/magento setup:di:compile
```

**2...**
install with `--search-engine=elasticsearch7`

> just tested with elasticsearch 8.6: installed with
> --search-engine=elasticsearch7  i dont see anything elasticsearch 8 related, when you change in menu to opensearch search engine, magento
> works ok

Source: Magento Github issue https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/37236

Comment: Perfect, thanks

Comment: @miller75 Cheers! Please mark the answer as **accepted**. That indicates your issue is **solved** and helps others with the same issue find out the verified answer easily.

Comment: I've been fighting with this for days... thanks for posting the work-around.

Comment: @Jon No worries. Glad to hear that :)

Comment: Tons of Thanks ! works perfectly with my dockergento 
```
  elasticsearch:
    tty: true
    image: elasticsearch:8.8.1
    environment:
      - discovery.type=single-node # may not have an effect
      - xpack.security.enabled=false
      - ELASTIC_USERNAME=username
      - ELASTIC_PASSWORD=password
    ports:
      - 9200:9200
    networks:
      - localswarm
    volumes:
      - esdata:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
```

Comment: Additionally I needed to update my ES settings with this `indices.id_field_data.enabled: true`. Otherwise the products would not show up, although the indexing worked flawlessly.

Comment: @codedge Yes, it is an additional step for Adobe Commerce that is not required for Magento Open Source. https://experienceleague.adobe.com/docs/commerce-operations/upgrade-guide/prepare/prerequisites.html

Comment: Well, it was required for me even with an local ES setup. Without my shop was empty, even though the indexing went fine.

Comment: It working for me