# issues when installing magento 2.4.6 on WSL2 ubuntu 22.04

Tags: elasticsearch, magento2.4.6, apache2, ubuntu, windows

Ok, let's move on. I am new to this and I am trying to install magento 2.4.6 on a local WSL server with Ubuntu 22.04, I have apache2, php8.1 and 8.2, composer, mysql and elasticsearch 8 installed.

I have 2 problems:

1. I installed Magento and I don't know how to access either the home or the admin, following several guides, this is the installation command I used:

```
bin/magento setup:install  --disable-modules=Magento_InventoryElasticsearch,Magento_Elasticsearch8,Magento_Elasticsearch,Magento_OpenSearch \
--base-url=http://local.core.com \
--db-host=localhost \
--db-name=magento \
--db-user=admin \
--db-password=admin \
--admin-firstname=admin \
--admin-lastname=admin \
--admin-email=admin@admin.com \
--admin-user=admin \
--admin-password=admin123 \
--language=en_US \
--currency=USD \
--timezone=America/Chicago \
--use-rewrites=1
```

i added this:

```
    ::1             localhost
    ::1             http://local.core.com
```

to the windows host file and it only returns the error: `ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED`

2. After the installation I couldn't get Magento to take elasticsearch following the guide on the official website and [this other question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/365651/magento-2-4-6-install-with-elasticsearch)  when using this command:

`curl --cacert /etc/elasticsearch/certs/http_ca.crt -u elastic:$ELASTIC_PASSWORD https://localhost:9200`

the answer is this:

```
{
  "name" : "Aksonyn-PC",
  "cluster_name" : "elasticsearch",
  "cluster_uuid" : "Vbm4-RXURbi0rk5NtKaNmQ",
  "version" : {
    "number" : "8.10.4",
    "build_flavor" : "default",
    "build_type" : "deb",
    "build_hash" : "b4a62ac808e886ff032700c391f45f1408b2538c",
    "build_date" : "2023-10-11T22:04:35.506990650Z",
    "build_snapshot" : false,
    "lucene_version" : "9.7.0",
    "minimum_wire_compatibility_version" : "7.17.0",
    "minimum_index_compatibility_version" : "7.0.0"
  },
  "tagline" : "You Know, for Search"
}
```

but when executing the command `php bin/magento setup:upgrade` it gives me the following error: **Could not validate a connection to Elasticsearch. No alive nodes. All the 1 nodes seem to be down.**

Comment: you have created virtual host and enable that site for this domain http://local.core.com?

Comment: if you could explain me better... If you could explain to me better, if you are referring to the apache .conf files in the `/etc/apache2/sites-available` path, I have 3 files
`000-default.conf`, `default-ssl.conf`, `magento2.conf`. `000-default.conf` have this `Listen 8080
<VirtualHost *:80>
 ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html
        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>`

Comment: and `magento2.conf` have this `<VirtualHost *:80>
     ServerAdmin admin@domain.com
     DocumentRoot /var/www/html/magento2/
     ServerName http://local.core.com

     <Directory /var/www/html/magento2/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
     </Directory>

     ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
     CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>`

Comment: try updating DocumentRoot /var/www/html/magento2/pub as your index files resides in pub directory

Comment: If I do that, the home loads without styles because due to the problem with elasticsearch I cannot run the compilation commands, and I don't know how to enter the admin

Comment: @ramsesadames please check this link https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/370719/82670

Answer (score 0):

Can you reach Elesaticsearch also by http instead of https ?

Comment: If I make the request through http the response is `curl: (52) Empty reply from server`

Answer (score 0):

I am applying below both codes. after then working

```
sudo systemctl stop elasticsearch.service

sudo systemctl start elasticsearch.service
```

After that, You can try the below commands for Magento installation.

```
php bin/magento setup:install --base-url="http://localhost/url/pub" --db-host="localhost" --db-name="db-name" --db-user="root" --db-password="" --admin-user="admin" --admin-password="admin@123" --admin-firstname="admin12" --admin-lastname="user" --admin-email="admin12@example.com" --backend-frontname="admin"
```

Answer (score 0):

> **Please add the below params to your bin/magento setup:install command.**

```
  --search-engine=SEARCH-ENGINE (Search engine. Values: elasticsearch5, elasticsearch7, elasticsearch8, opensearch)
  --elasticsearch-host=ELASTICSEARCH-HOST (Elasticsearch server host.)
  --elasticsearch-port=ELASTICSEARCH-PORT (Elasticsearch server port.)
  --elasticsearch-enable-auth=ELASTICSEARCH-ENABLE-AUTH (Set to 1 to enable authentication. (default is 0, disabled))
  --elasticsearch-username=ELASTICSEARCH-USERNAME (Elasticsearch username. Only applicable if HTTP auth is enabled)
  --elasticsearch-password=ELASTICSEARCH-PASSWORD (Elasticsearch password. Only applicable if HTTP auth is enabled)
  --elasticsearch-index-prefix=ELASTICSEARCH-INDEX-PREFIX (Elasticsearch index prefix.)
```

> **Please check below curl command**

```
curl -X GET --user username:password "http://localhost:9200"
```