# Can't create product with stock

Tags: magento2, product, elasticsearch, indexing

I'm trying to create a product with stock (quantity), so I can do an example purchase. But whenever I try to create a product, I get the following error: "The stock item was unable to be saved. Please try again." (first picture). I got a little deeper, went to the logs and found out the following error when trying to create a product:

`[2023-12-13T19:31:30.664971+00:00] main.ERROR: {"error":"no handler found for uri [/magento2_product_1_v1/document/_bulk] and method [POST]"} [] []`

`[2023-12-13T19:31:30.694164+00:00] main.CRITICAL: Exception message: The stock item was unable to be saved. Please try again.`

I also went to the Index Managment tab and found out that Catalog Search needs a reindex (second picture), but when I ran `bin/magento index:reindex` on console I got the following error: `{"error":"no handler found for uri [/magento2_product_1_v2/document/_mapping] and method [PUT]"}`. I'm guessing that both errors are related or maybe one contains the other, but I'm struggling to find the solution.

I'm using Magento v2.4.6-p1 and Elasticsearch 7.17.4, so I think it is not a compatibility problem as signaled in various posts. I also have my elasticsearch server running (I curl to `localhost:9200` and I get a JSON response). I read in the [following link](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/354934/getting-error-while-execute-php-bin-magento-indexerreindex-please-guide) that I had to add some configuration to elasticsearch, so I vimmed into /opt/homebrew/etc/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.yml (I'm using Mac M1) and added `indices.id_field_data.enabled: true`, but it didn't work.

I ran out of ideas, so any help would be appreciated!

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone steps with this issue, I managed to get it working by changing from elasticsearch to opensearch. To manage so, I installed opensearch, get it up and working and then went to Stores -> Configuration -> Catalog -> Catalog -> Catalog Search, then change the search engine from elasticsearch to opensearch and (successfully) test the connection.

Answer (score 0):

please try to reset the indexer so please apply the below commands in your Magento root directory.

```
php bin/magento indexer:reset
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
php bin/magento indexer:status
```

The above step not working so please try to below step.

1): first back up your database.

2): then run

`INSERT INTO cataloginventory_stock (stock_id, website_id, stock_name) VALUES ('1', '1', 'default');`

Comment: Hi, I did went through those commands, but it didn't work, the error just kept happening. I think I won't try with the second one as I managed to get it working with opensearch instead of elasticsearch. Thanks anyway!